# Can't pass another argument next to event argument. e.preventDefault is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Good evening,

I want to cause a delay after click a Link from React Router.
Everything is fine with this code:

```
    const delayFunction = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(() => {
            history.push('/About');
        }, 2000);
    };
```

**My problem:** I want to add "path" argument next to "e" argument because static path '/About' is useless when I map all my Links. When I try to do that I got an error:

```
TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function
```

I do need this. I tried with adding path argument but still have been not knowing how to solve this.

code:

```
const HeaderList = ({ open, showheader, pageContext, changeSection }) => {
    const [items] = useState([
        { pathname: 'projects', path: routes.projects },
        { pathname: 'services', path: routes.services },
        { pathname: 'about', path: routes.about },
        { pathname: 'contact', path: routes.contact },
    ]);

    const history = useHistory();

    const delayFunction = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(() => {
            history.push('/projects');
        }, 2000);
    };

   const history = useHistory();
    const delayRedirect = path => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            history.push(path);
            console.log(path);
            console.log(history);
        }, 5000);
    }

    return (
        <StyledList open={open}>
            {items.map(({ pathname, path }) => {
                return (
                    <StyledListItem key={pathname}>
                        <StyledLink
                            key={pathname}
                            to={path}
                            pagetype={pageContext}
                            showheader={showheader ? 1 : 0}
                            onClick={() => delayFunction(path)}
                        >
                            {pathname}
                        </StyledLink>
                    </StyledListItem>
                );
            })}
        </StyledList>
    );
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass event as an argument `onClick={(e) => delayFunction(e, path)}`

and then `delayFunction` function can accept `e, path` as parameters

`delayFunction(e, path)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, forgot about this.

Answer (score 1):

Change `onClick={() => delayFunction(path)}` to `onClick={e => delayFunction(e, path)}`
and change the params in delayFunction's header.

Comment: Thanks a lot, forgot about this